# VAST ad playback for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, vast

In my radio app(written in Swift) I'm trying to do VAST request, receive the response, parse it and play the ad (audio, video, companion). Is there any framework to do all that stuff. I saw that there is a Google IMA framework for that but I can't find how it is handling the audio ads, cause while receiving audio ads I need to pause the player, play that audio ad and only then resume the player (so I don't need to show a video player for audio ads). Is there any suggestions?